# Is it possible to place Google Drive to the Network Location section in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-drive, google-drive

For me it would be intuitive if Google Drive would be inside Network Location section inside My Computer window.

[image]

Is this something that can be done with little amount of hacking?

Comment: The Google Drive is a *local* folder that is synced to the network when/if a connection is available. This aspect is different from a network drive where if you lose connectivity you lose access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Brian said on his comment:

"The Google Drive is a local folder that is synced to the network when/if a connection is available. This aspect is different from a network drive where if you lose connectivity you lose access to it."